# Преобразование строки в Java

Tags: java

Как мне преобразовать строку, которая содержит плавающую точку (44470.0)в Integer???

Comment: С округлением или отсечением?

Comment: Integer.parse("44470.0")

Comment: Integer.parseInt() вызывает exception так что не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
int i = (int) Double.parseDouble("44470.0");
```

Все цифры после точки  будут отброшены, `i` будет равно 44470.

Answer (score 0):

Просто округлить дробь:

```
int d = (int) Double.parseDouble("44470.0");
```

Если хотите округлить то самый простой способ это добавлять 0.5 к дроби:

```
int d = (int) (Double.parseDouble("44470.0")+0.5);
```